# Junit: How to know line number in parameter file

Tags: java, junit

I have a method in junit that is responsible for checking errors in a very large file (more than 200k lines).

I would like to know if there is any variable in which Junit put the lines that have the file and the line in which he is doing the test, in order to use them.

I know that in testCase() there is a private variable that contains the line on which the test is running, but I can not access it, any advice?

The code used is like this:

```
@Test
@FileParameters("fileparameter")
public void testFechaAlteracionExpedienteFS(String line) {
String TEST= 'test';
assertThat(TEST).overridingErrorMessage("Expected: <%s> - but it was: <%s>", line, TEST, ConstantesSql.getConsulta()).isEqualTo(line);
```

I'm using Maven with Junit 4+.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple java api?

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-

Comment: Maybe to know the number of lines is ok, but i need the number of the line that is testing too. Junit handles the file control, so I guess somehow you can access that information.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized test:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    @Parameter(0)
    public File file;

    @Parameter(1)
    public String line;

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Object[][] { { new File("/path/to/file1"), "line1" },
                        { new File("/path/to/file2"), "line2" },
                        { new File("/path/to/file3"), "line3" } });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Your test code here (read file and line variables)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is the file has a variable size, furthermore this method obligates me to read every line in the file.

Anyway, thanks.